# Update metadata of object in Google Cloud Storage with Java/Kotlin gives NullPointerExceptions

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

I have created a function to update metadata of an object in Google Cloud Storage.

```kotlin
fun updateUserMetadata(objectName: String, userMetadata: Map<String, String>) {
    val blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, basePath + objectName)
    val blobInfo: BlobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId)
            .setMetadata(userMetadata)
            .build()
    storage.update(blobInfo)
}
```

Somehow this function always gives me the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId.fromPb(BlobId.java:119)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo.fromPb(BlobInfo.java:1029)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.fromPb(Blob.java:918)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.update(StorageImpl.java:428)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.update(StorageImpl.java:447)
    at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.gcp.cloudstorage.CloudStorageBase.updateUserMetadata(CloudStorageBase.kt:88)
    at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.gcp.cloudstorage.CloudStorageBaseTest.testUpdateUserMetadata(CloudStorageBaseTest.kt:71)
```

In the function above non of the variables are null.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into how you are passing things and I first did not see anything directly wrong. What I found though makes total sense and I hope helps you in finding a solution is this:

```
gsObjectName - the object name of this Blob, if it is stored on Google Cloud Storage, null otherwise.
```

I'm inclining towards it being a pathing issue on how you are pointing to the GCS object. It not being able to reach where you are pointing would explain why a nullpointer is raised.

I would recommend revising the way you are pointing to the path of the GCS object.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

I've found another thing that might help you solve the issue. This is a similar way of doing what you are attempting to do and the different perspective might help you out.

Have a look [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/b6a364a101560f0eb7499176649b53f3cab08854/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/snippets/StorageSnippets.java#L312)